# Android service not running

Tags: android, service, android-service

I followed the official documentation to implement a Service that runs indefinitely and checks for Firebase Database changes and sends a notification. I want the service to run even when the app is killed. I looked at other Stack Overflow posts, but most of them start their Service from an Activity, but I don't want to do that because I want the Service to run even when the app is not started/running. The Service is not running at all and I am not sure why. Thanks in advance.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
  <service android:name=".service.DbService" />
```

Code:

```
import android.app.*
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat
import com.google.firebase.database.*

class DbService : Service() {

    private lateinit var dbRef: DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate() {
        Log.d("Service", " +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ onCreate");
//        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("messeges")
        createNotificationChannel()
        dbRef.addChildEventListener(dbListener)
    }

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d("Service", " +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ onStartCommand");
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        dbRef.removeEventListener(dbListener)
    }

    private val dbListener = object : ChildEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun onChildMoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
            with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)) {
                // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
                notify(DBEventID, notification())
            }
        }

        override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
            Log.d("Service", " +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ onChildAdded");
            with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)) {
                // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
                notify(DBEventID, notification())
            }
        }

        override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)) {
                // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
                notify(DBEventID, notification())
            }
        }
    }

    private fun notification(): Notification {

        // Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)

        return NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_round_test)
            .setLargeIcon(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.resources, R.drawable.ic_launcher_round_test)
            )
            .setContentTitle("test")
            .setContentText("lalala test")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
//            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            //.setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500)
            // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build()
    }

    // you should execute this code as soon as your app starts
    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            //     val name = getString(R.string.channel_name)
            // val descriptionText = getString(R.string.channel_description)
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            val channel =
                NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "channel name (change)", importance).apply {
                    description = "notification descripton"//descriptionText
                    enableLights(true)
                    lightColor = getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
                }
            // Register the channel with the system
            val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val CHANNEL_ID = "Listing Update notifier"
        private const val DBEventID = 12345
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up starting the Service from the MainActivty onDestroy method, Now it works but I don't think it's efficient. Please let me know if there is more efficient method for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Service in the background to check for server update is not efficient. Multiple devices will be making unnecessary requests to check server updates which very inefficient and wastes battery.

The most efficient way I found is to use Firebase Functions. I wrote server-side js code that checks for updates on incoming requests and sends a notification to a specific device if needed.

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple